# Display Average in PyQtGraph

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

I'm curious on how to use the [average feature](https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/blob/5195d9dd6308caee87e043e859e7e553b9887453/pyqtgraph/graphicsItems/PlotItem/PlotItem.py#L16) in PyQtGraph (accessible through the context menu `Plot Options` > `Average`).

**What I would expect to happen:**
I have a plot with a curve, that continuously updates. When I activate average I can choose over how many traces the curve is averaged and displayed. I end up with a curve, that updates more smoothly. It would also be good to disable the original (unaveraged) curve. This functionality is very common in modern oscilloscopes for example.

**What happens:**
I open the example `Benchmarks` > `Line Plot update` and select `Average`. Then the original curve continues updating (white), and a new curve appears which is a copy of the curve at the time when I activated the average button (I think). The field below `Average` stays empty.

[image: Example with Averaging]

I have the feeling that I misunderstood how this averaging functionality works. In the [source code](https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/blob/5195d9dd6308caee87e043e859e7e553b9887453/pyqtgraph/graphicsItems/PlotItem/PlotItem.py#L431) it looks like you can average over a specified parameter, but I have no idea how to define one.

Can anybody resolve this confusion for me, or is this feature documented somewhere (I cannot find anything)?

Answer (score 0):

By checking the button, an average curve of multiple curves on the graph will be plotted with a green pen.

Show as below, the green curve is plotting the average data of the two white curves.
[image]

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
import pyqtgraph as pg


class Draw_interface(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Draw_interface, self).__init__()
  
        p1 = pg.PlotWidget(name = "Plot1")
        
        # Draw charts
        y = [2.2, 3.0, 1.3, 2.5, 1.9, 2.2, 5.5, 6.6]
        y2 = [2.3, 3.3, 2.8, 2.2, 3.3, 3.1, 2.8, 4.4]
        p1.plot(y)
        p1.plot(y2)

        l = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        l.addWidget(p1)
        w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        w.setLayout(l)
        self.setCentralWidget(w)
        self.setStyleSheet("QWidget { background-color: black; }")
    
def main():
    QtWidgets.QApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.HighDpiScaleFactorRoundingPolicy.PassThrough)
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    main = Draw_interface()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```